# Download SSRS report in xslx format via asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I try to download SSRS report in xlsx via web request.

```
var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 5;
wr.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
wr.PreAuthenticate = true;
wr.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
wr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse()
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
```

It works fine if I use this code in console application, response return xlsx file.
But in ASP.NET app in response I get text/html content-type.
I think it's authentication html page. How can I get xlsx file?

Comment: What is the response content with the Asp.Net application?

Comment: yeah don't do this, call the ReportServer API and generate the XLSX using GetReport or whatever it is called these days and stream that back.

Comment: use following link:  http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2015/07/print-export-ssrs-report-in-aspnet.html

Comment: I changed 'wr.PreAuthenticate = true;' to 'wr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);' and it helps to solve problem.